# What’s this small metal post sticking out of my wall?

Tags: walls, exterior, brick

Down the side of my UK house there is this thing sticking out of my wall. There’s a gas fire on the other side of that means anything. It sticks out about 2 inches I would say.

Can I cut it down or pull it out?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't strike me as a functional component of the wall, as a brick tie or weep string might. I can't imagine how it would relate to the fireplace. It was probably for hanging something decorative or utilitarian.

Wiggle it gently as you pull with a pliers. Consider filling the hole with matching caulk or cement patch to prevent leaks and freeze damage.

Or hang an old shoe on it, just to keep folks guessing.

[image]